Kotlin error "Type argument is not within its bounds" related to fun interface and annotations
I was working on a simple project with Kotlin in IntelliJ IDEA, when I encountered an odd compile-time error by the IDE, which read:
Type argument is not within its bounds.

This was being shown for a type argument that was within its bounds!
It took a while to produce an MRU for the error, and here it is:
fun interface I { fun f() }

annotation class A<T : I>

@A<C>
class C : I { override fun f() {} }

In this code, as you can see, C is a subtype of I, but the IDE still shows a compile-time error at the C in the @A<C> line, which says:
Type argument is not within its bounds.
Expected: I
Found: C

This is clearly a bug.
The weird part is, the bug goes away if I is not a fun interface and is just a simple interface. Very strange.
My question is, what do I do now? Is this a bug or is my code wrong?
EDIT: the bug doesn't go away by simply making I an interface; however, it does go away by also removing f. Still strange.
EDIT 2: Since broot asked, here's what my code is for:
fun interface Saveable { fun save(it: DataOutputStream) }

@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class Loadable<T : Saveable>(val loaderClass: KClass<out Loader<T>>)

@Loadable<Example>(loaderClass = ExampleLoader::class)
class Example(...) : Saveable {
    override fun save(it: DataOutputStream) { ... }
}

// ...

fun interface Loader<T : Saveable> { fun load(it: DataInputStream): T }

class ExampleLoader : Loader<Example> {
    override fun load(it: DataInputStream): Example {
        return Example(...)
    }
}

EDIT 3: Here's the functionality that would be lost if we removed T from Loadable:
fun <T : Saveable> getLoader(c: KClass<T>): Loader<T> {
    val l = c.annotations.filterIsInstance<Loadable>()
    when (l.size) {
        0 -> throw Exception("${c.simpleName} is not Loadable")
        1 -> {
            val loaderClass = l[0].loaderClass
            val constructor = loaderClass.primaryConstructor
                ?: throw Error("Loader class ${c.simpleName} for ${loaderClass.simpleName} has no primary constructor")
            return constructor.call() as Loader<T>
        }

        else -> throw Exception("${c.simpleName} must only be annotated as Loadable once")
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : Saveable> getLoader(): Loader<T> {
    return getLoader(T::class)
}

If Loadable didn't have access to T (where T : Saveable), we can't get the Loader of a Saveable type in a type-safe and "checked" way, and we have to resort to manual casting and ignoring type-safety warnings.

On first sight it looks like some kind of a bug in the compiler/IDE, but frankly speaking, it seems pretty strange to use a generic annotation class. How is this useful?

Apparently, problem is somehow related to the fact you annotate C using C in the annotation. Maybe it fails in some kind of circular dependency. It doesn't always happen for me, it sometimes shows as fine. And it always works if I annotate another type, without circular dependency.

@broot I added the answer to your "how is this useful" question; and yes it sometimes shows as fine for me as well, only to fail upon compilation, and yes it works when I annotate another type, but given my use-case, I need to annotate the class itself. Any idea what I should do?

Well, you provided an example on how you would like to use it, but it still doesn't answer my question: how is it useful that the annotation is generic? Or maybe I'll rephrase my question: what if we simply remove the T in Loadable? Will we lose any functionality? Usually, we need generic types, because we pass instances of a class between places, we store them in variables, etc. We don't do this with annotations.

How is the Loadable annotation being used? If you're, e.g., using them at run-time to create an instance of the specified Loader type, does the generic remove the need for unchecked casts? Or is it no different than annotation class Loadable(loader: KClass<out Saveable>)?

Seems to only affect Kotlin/JVM. It compiles successfully on Kotlin/JS. And I cannot reproduce "the bug goes away if I is not a fun interface and is just a simple interface" either. See also It should be an error to declare a generic annotation class.

@broot Please read EDIT 3, where I've answered your question of "will we lose any functionality".

@Slaw Please read EDIT 3, where I've answered your question of "how is the Loadable annotation being used".

@Sweeper then it is obviously a bug/quirk of the JVM Kotlin implementation; and please read the first edit where I've clarified how the bug goes away.

@Sweeper I read the youtrack thread you linked, and commented my counter-argument to it in there.

@SMMH And what is the part that would not work? As expected, you didn't use the T anywhere, because that would be pretty unusual. I think your code works exactly the same no matter if the annotation is generic or not: https://pl.kotl.in/ulcImcS22 (it doesn't compile only because the Playground doesn't support full reflection)

@SMMH Using the JLS to argue that this should be allowed is a pretty bad argument IMO. Newer versions of the JLS specifically says that a (Java) annotation cannot be generic. Not to mention that this is about Kotlin, not Java.

@SMMH You seem to think that without making the annotation generic, it somehow won't be able to store KClass in its props or it will be somehow weakly typed or something, This is not true. Generic annotation would make sense only if you would pass typed instances of Loadable (not Loader) from places to places and do some advanced stuff with them. This is a very unusual case, although technically potentially possible. So far you didn't show any code that would do this, so the annotation doesn't benefit from being generic.

I agree with broot. It wouldn't be type-safe either way, because T is erased. You can avoid the as Loader<T> unchecked cast, but that doesn't mean it's checked either. filterIsInstance cannot distinguish between a Loadable<Foo> and a Loadable<Bar>. It is still possible to accidentally write getLoader(Foo::class) and get something that is a Loader<Bar>, and when you try to load a Foo with that, you get a class cast exception.

@Sweeper sorry the code I pasted was a newer one; in the previous one it had filterIsInstance<Loadable<T>> and the as Loader<T> was not necessary. That, coupled with the inline getLoader lets you do stuff like getLoader<Example>() which gives you an instance of ExampleLoader, all of type-checked.

@broot @Sweeper Thank you for your help, and I've decided to ditch the T in Loadable, not because it wasn't useful for my case but because of the circularity in reference, which is, as you pointed out, also why the compiler complains about it.

Yes, I understand that you had filterIsInstance<Loadable<T>>, and my point is that this still cannot check whether it is a Loader<Foo> or Loader<Bar>.See https://pl.kotl.in/AMt6rgWZb. filterIsInstance is not magic. It can't recover erased type information. What you can do, if annotations can be generic, is to store an extra KClass<T> in the annotation, in addition to KClass<Loader<T>>. Then it can be type-checked.

@SMMH Please note filterIsInstance<Loadable<T>> is not in any way more type-safe than as Loader<T>. Both solutions don't check T. If you have multiple extensions over the Loadable and they do something with T, then it could be beneficial to have the annotation generic. But still, it feels smelly to add a logic to the Loadable itself and not to the Loader.

One potential use case related to the above is if the annotation references both a loader and "saver" for the exactly same type. Then we could actually benefit from making the annotation generic to ensure the matching T. But still, it feels like an overkill for something which is just a simple metadata associated with the code.

@broot @Sweeper the reason filterIsInstance<Loadable<T>> "felt" more type-safe than as Loader<T> was because the former did not raise compile-time warnings while the latter did. But I understand now that they are equally type-unsafe. Thank you.

@SMMH Yes, this is actually something I really don't like in Kotlin stdlib. This function performs unchecked casts, but it doesn't generate any warnings and doesn't even mention this in the documentation :-/
